# PR_SEARCH_KEY using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I need to extract **PR_SEARCH_KEY** for some mails using **EWS**. I was doing it using Outlook API earlier. But I want to re-write complete code in EWS as it is much powerful.

**Old code:**

```
private String GetLnksForMailBoxMails(Outlook.MailItem mail)
        {
            const string PR_SEARCH_KEY =
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x300B0102";

            Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = mail.PropertyAccessor;
            String searchKey = pa.BinaryToString(pa.GetProperty(PR_SEARCH_KEY));
            //    Console.WriteLine("Here is lnks for normal mail box:{0} ", searchKey);
            return searchKey;
        }
```

**New Code:**

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition eDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x300B, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
                PropertySet prop = BasePropertySet.IdOnly;
                prop.Add(eDef);
                ItemView ivItemView = new ItemView(5000);
                ivItemView.PropertySet = prop;
```

But I am not able to get String value for it.

Comment: http://gsexdev.blogspot.in/2012/09/finding-and-removing-duplicate-items.html. I have got the answer from the implementation of PR_SEARCH_KEY here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a Binary property so what you will get back is a Binary Array if you want to get the same Hex String as in the OOM just use something ilke

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition eDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x300B, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
        PropertySet prop = BasePropertySet.IdOnly;
        prop.Add(eDef);
        ItemView ivItemView = new ItemView(1000);
        ivItemView.PropertySet = prop;
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = Inbox.FindItems(ivItemView);
        foreach (Item itItem in fiResults) {
            Byte[] PropVal;
            String HexSearchKey;
            if (itItem.TryGetProperty(eDef, out PropVal)) {
                HexSearchKey = BitConverter.ToString(PropVal).Replace("-", "");
                Console.WriteLine(HexSearchKey);
            }

        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I just figured out. But as you have taken pain to post the answer. I have marked your answer as answer :)