# Getting the email id from the Outlook REST API when sending email

Tags: office365-restapi

I am trying to use the Microsoft Rest API to send emails on behalf of our users. When I create a message as a draft, I get back an ID that I can use in future requests for editing, deleting, viewing the full conversation (after it is sent), etc.

I do not want to save it as a draft since I have no reason to, I just want to send it directly. After it is sent, I would still like to view the full conversation. However, if I just send the email (using the /sendmail endpoint), I do not get that ID. Is there anyway to get it? Here is my request:

POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users/email/sendmail

```
{
    "Message": {
        "Subject": "Test",
        "Importance": "Normal",
        "ToRecipients": [{
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Address": "<email>",
                "Name": "<name>"
            }
        }],
        "Sender": {
            "EmailAddress": {
                "Address": "<email",
                "Name": "<name>"
            }
        },
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "<html>\\n<head>\\n  <style>\\n    p { color: red; }\\n  </style> \\n</head>\\n<body>\\n  <p>Test</p>\\n</body>\\n</html>\\n"
        }
    },
    "SaveToSentItems": "true"
}
```

The HTTP response code is 202, the email sends, but the body is empty (no content, whatsoever).

I don't think this matters, since I can recreate this in Postman, but I am running this in Nodejs using the node-outlook package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails in Exchange via REST and EWS are *submitted* for transport, but the actual send and subsequent save to the sent items folder are done async.  This is why you don't get the id.  Transport is who actually writes the email to the sent items folder, not REST.

If you really need to find the item after it has been saved to the sentItems folder, set something like the PR_SEARCH_KEY and then do a view of the sent items folder and seek to that search key value.

Also note when you save a draft, the id that you get back will be different than the id of the item in the sent items folder because the folder Id is part of the id of the item, so that id wouldn't help you anyways.

Comment: Yeah, that seems more like what I'm looking for. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it in the REST API, probably because I'm not very familiar with the Outlook API in general. I think that this is the document I am looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations, but I am having trouble figuring out how to identify the property (name, guid, etc). Would you happen to have an example of how to use it?

Comment: Ok, I got it working by adding this to the message: `"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [{"PropertyId":"String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1C} Id 0x300B","Value":"1"}]`, but I still don't understand why it works. In particular, I don't understand what the GUID is for.

Comment: Guid is simply a namespace.  The above means property 0x300B in namespace <Guid>.  MAPI does that so that 0x300B in my namespace doesn't conflict with 0x300B in your namespace.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. So it doesn't matter what it is, so long as no one else is using the same value that I am using?

Comment: Well that depends on what you want to do :)  In your above extended prop, you are setting some custom property that you have defined.  That is completely fine.  However, if you want to set the PR_SEARCHKEY, you would need to use the PropertyTag format for the extended property.  PropertyTags are for well known, MAPI based properties.  You are correct that the value is "0x300B", but it doesn't require a namespace nor an id since it is a well known prop.  So instead use something like:  "PropertyId": "Binary 0x300B").

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Outlook, so I don't really know what PR_SEARCHKEY is. I have since changed my code to use `        SingleValueExtendedProperties: [{ PropertyId: "String {8ECCC264-6880-4EBE-992F-8888D2EEAA1C} Name PR_SEARCH_KEY", Value: <my id>, }]` because I liked using the name instead of a hex value, and it seemed from the rather sparse documentation that they should be equivalent. This works, although I have noticed that querying for the email using that value is rather slow. Currently I am using it when I send email to make sure that I haven't already sent it.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what you just said, it sounds like I can define any property with whatever name or id I feel like (obviously within some limitations), and use it however I feel like, and that what you are referring to is some well-known property in some global namespace called PR_SEARCH_KEY? And that that is not what I have been setting, but because of how I've been using it, it works anyway? (also, is it PR_SEARCH_KEY or PR_SEARCHKEY, you've used it both ways?)

Comment: Regarding perf, notice my comments above though:  If you really need to find the item after it has been saved to the sentItems folder, **set something like the PR_SEARCH_KEY and then do a view of the sent items folder and seek to that search key value.**

Comment: Didn't mean to hit enter there.  Continuing... The Exchange store isn't like SQL.  If you have a varying restriction (query statement), the store has to build an index each time.  Restrictions are good for things that don't change - stuff like "Where FolderSize > 1000" and the 1000 never changes.  For things that change regularly like YourProp = myId, it is best to do a FindItem, sorted by creationDate descending and by myId and then use a SeekToCondition to do a server side seek to the condition.  You should be able to see the syntax for SeekToCondition online somewhere.

Comment: @DavidSterling-MSFT I've tried what you've suggested, but it says **The property 'PR_SEARCH_KEY' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.**
How do I mark the type as open type?

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear.  PR_SEARCH_KEY is a MAPI property, so you would reference it by extended property:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818502/pr-search-key-using-ews

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which rest api version are you using (i'm using v2.0) but i will try to explain this issue. Sorry for my english i advance.

You have 2 ways to reply a message: **on the fly** way or **the complete** way.

### On the fly way

Its the easy way, just send a **post** request to

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/reply

or

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/replyall

and with the body

```
{
  "Comment": "This is your message in plain text or html code"
}
```

and thats all.

The problem with this methos that you can only send plain text or HTML, no attachments or anything else. If that's all you need this is your best option.

### The complete way

If you need to send an attachment or perform any other action you need to perform these 3 steps:

*1. Create a draft from the message you want to reply*

Send a **post** request to

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{message_id}/createreply

This will give you an json object save the "Id" property {draft_id} of this draft for later use.

*2. Update the draft*

Send a **patch** request to

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{draft_id}

and with the body

```
{
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML or Text",
    "Content": "Your response in plain text or html"
  }
}
```

or any other parameter you want to change.

*3. Send the draft*

Send a **post** request to

> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{draft_id}/send

And thats it.

If you need more info abut this check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Comment: Wow. I forgot about this question, it's been a while, and I don't use the Outlook Rest API anymore. Your answer has a lot of useful content, but it's not answering the question that was asked. The original question was about receiving a reply made by someone else to an email that I originally sent (via the api), which is a very unusual circumstance. I did manage to solve the problem via extended properties, with the information provided by David Sterling as a starting point.