# EWS Find Items by PR_SEARCH_KEY

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, exchangewebservices

I managed to get the PR_SEARCH_KEY from some email items as described in [PR_SEARCH_KEY using EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818502/pr-search-key-using-ews) but now I wonder how I can search items with this key in C# (.net-core).

Cheers
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the HexValue you have back to a Binary and then to Base64 and you can then use it in a SearchFilter when searching a foldereg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition eDef = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x300B, MapiPropertyType.Binary);    
        ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(eDef ,Convert.ToBase64String(searchval));
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiItems = Folder.FindItems(sf, iv);
```